# iOS set video frame rate

Tags: ios, avfoundation, frame-rate, slowmotion

I want to set the frame rate for a specific video (whose `fps` value is < 30.0f) to make it with a slow-motion effect. I tried to look at the `nominalFrameRate` property of `AVAssetTrack`, but this property is read-only.
Does anybody know a way in the iOS SDK to set the frame rate?